# getCellType() always returns 0 (Numeric)

Tags: java, apache-poi

When I read an xls file with Apache POI, I always receive the value `0` from `getCellType()`. That is incorrect. I have other types of data inserted in the sheet. And I don't really understand why this is happening.

This is what my logger says every time it parses a cell:

```
Type = 0
```

Does anyone know or have a clue why is this happening?

```
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

        HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row; 
        HSSFCell cell;

        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext())
        {
            row=(HSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

            while (cells.hasNext())
            {   
                cell=(HSSFCell) cells.next(); 
                log4Debug.debug(" cellCollumnr = "+cell.getCellNum());
                log4Debug.debug(" cellRow = "+row.getRowNum());
                log4Debug.debug(" Type = "+cell.getCellType());
            }
       }
```

Comment: Do you mean you're getting a type of `0` for a String or Formula cell? If so, are you sure you are checking the cell you meant to check?

Comment: I am sure, I am checking the right cell. My log actually show me the coordinates of cell and type of it. And it gives me something like:
CellCollumn = 0 CellRow = 0 Type = 0
The same for 0,1 - 0,2 - etc

Comment: And what is the actual type of those cells? Formula? String? Empty? Error?

Comment: I use different type of data. Mostly Date and String.

@Kayaman I have edited my post and added the code.

Comment: Well, nothing obviously wrong with the code shown. Is it possible the Excel file is.... *cursed*? Try creating a new file with a single String cell and see if the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Date isn't an Excel cell type though! It's a numeric cell with formatting applied....

Comment: For information on how to distinguish between date cell values and numeric cell values, see [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents). Both are of type `NUMERIC` but for date cells `DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)` returns `true`.